# Windows Azure - HDD Size

Tags: azure

I am playing with Windows Azure to create an small VM to host a service that almost doesn't take any space.

Windows Azure creates a default 130gb disk, with about 100gb free. That's way too much. I do not need that much space.

I understand that MSFT will charge the storage (ie: the 130gb), so I would like to create the VM smaller (probably 30 or 40gb).

1. Is it true that MSFT will charge me for the unused space?
2. Is there a way to create the machine the size I want?
3. If there is no way to create the machine in the size I want, how to resize? (the option to download the .vhd to my computer and resize here looks way too much effort to say the less).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In azure only space really used is billed. For Linux VM, sadly, the whole space is billed.
You can verify how much a drive costs you with some tools like [IaaS Management Studio](http://iaas.ao-is.com/) (works in the free version).

Answer (score 2):

In my practise is frist run VM shrink disk with data - i use this script:
Get-Volume c | resize-partition -size (40GB -1MB)

And next you can use CloudExplorer

Solutions: http://mijndertstuij.nl/resize-the-root-volume-of-an-azure-vm/

1. For shrink disk you must firs click Acquire lease
2. Click shrink diks and click button down with GB (if you write in input window this can't work) > click ok
3. Click Break lease

Answer (score 0):

I also asked in Stackoverflow with seems to be the place that MSFT monitors for Azure.

I got an answer, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192531/windows-azure-hdd-size/16192797?noredirect=1#16192797