# Azure Maximum attached disk size, and billing

Tags: azure, direct-attached-storage, maximum

Some context: I want to setup an ES cluster on Azure. Data nodes should be w/ 10 shards/replicas of 1 To each, which means 10To "data" disk on each node. Nodes run on linux.

Questions:

- AFAIK I can add disk with a maximum size of 1To. Am I limited to create a software raid0 to reach the 10To goal (with VMs types that allow 10 attached disks)?
- I read on [Windows Azure - HDD Size](https://serverfault.com/questions/502047/windows-azure-hdd-size) (1 year old) that billing is set to the whole disk on Linux machines, is that still the case ? And does anyone know the tech limitation for this behavior ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the maximum size of VM HDD is 1TB and Yes, You must create software RAID to get bigger size for filesystem.
2. Billing is set to storage You are really used not for whole disk - in standard storage. In premium storage (SSD) You pay for disk, not storage really used. Here You have good to read article about storage in Azure: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/16/azure-premium-storage-now-generally-available-2